# PowerShell loop performance: why does adding a function call make this loop faster?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell's [scripting performance documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations) outlines the following example:

```
$ranGen = New-Object System.Random
$RepeatCount = 10000

'Basic for-loop = {0}ms' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
        $Null = $ranGen.Next()
    }
}).TotalMilliseconds

'Wrapped in a function = {0}ms' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {
    function Get-RandNum_Core {
        param ($ranGen)
        $ranGen.Next()
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
        $Null = Get-RandNum_Core $ranGen
    }
}).TotalMilliseconds

'For-loop in a function = {0}ms' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {
    function Get-RandNum_All {
        param ($ranGen)
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
            $Null = $ranGen.Next()
        }
    }

    Get-RandNum_All $ranGen
}).TotalMilliseconds
```

and shows the following sample output/timings:

```
Basic for-loop = 47.8668ms
Wrapped in a function = 820.1396ms
For-loop in a function = 23.3193ms
```

When I run the sample on my machine, I get similar results where the 3rd example is significantly faster than the 1st.

It makes sense that the 2nd example is by far the slowest because the cost of the function call is incurred for each loop iteration.  **Question**: But why is the 3rd example is so much faster than the 1st?  If anything, I would expect it to be a bit slower because the only difference when compared to the 1st is that there is one additional function call.

Comment: What happens if you change the order of execution? Swap 1 and 3.

Comment: Variable scope locality has a huge impact on runtime performance in PowerShell. Try adding `$local:ranGen = $ranGen` before the loop in the first example, or wrap in `&{param($ranGen) ... } $ranGen` to see a similar improvement

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: the scope by itself doesn't fully explain the discrepancy, which remains significant even if all variables are explicitly made local. The change from a bare block to a parameterized one is what brings things in line with the function call. In fact, calling a block is faster even with *no* parameters and no changes to scope. The ways of the PowerShell interpreter are strange.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I dont follow "calling a block is faster even with no params and no changes to scope".  Can you provide an example that I can add to my answer which has a bunch of test variations?

Comment: This is variation C in your test setup.

Answer (score 1):

After making the suggested changes by [Mathias in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732918/powershell-loop-performance-why-does-adding-a-function-call-make-this-loop-fast#comment133599740_75732918) I'm seeing consistent results and the `for` loop in example 1 being faster than example 3. Also for fairness, these benchmarks should run in their own scope and not affect the session state by any means, since `Measure-Command` script block is **dot sourced**, ideally a new script block should be added to these calls and the same should be invoked with the call operator `&`.

```bash
$ranGen = New-Object System.Random
$RepeatCount = 10000

0..5 | ForEach-Object {
    'Iteration {0}' -f $_
    ''

    'Basic for-loop = {0}ms' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {&{
        param($RepeatCount, $ranGen)

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
            $Null = $ranGen.Next()
        }
    } $RepeatCount $ranGen}).TotalMilliseconds

    'Wrapped in a function = {0}ms' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {&{
        param($RepeatCount, $ranGen)

        function Get-RandNum_Core {
            param ($ranGen)
            $ranGen.Next()
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
            $Null = Get-RandNum_Core $ranGen
        }
    } $RepeatCount $ranGen}).TotalMilliseconds

    'For-loop in a function = {0}ms' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {&{
        param($RepeatCount, $ranGen)

        function Get-RandNum_All {
            param ($ranGen)
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
                $Null = $ranGen.Next()
            }
        }

        Get-RandNum_All $ranGen
    } $RepeatCount $ranGen}).TotalMilliseconds

    ''
}
```

Results:

```
Iteration 0

Basic for-loop = 6.5823ms
Wrapped in a function = 185.169ms
For-loop in a function = 9.8188ms

Iteration 1

Basic for-loop = 2.3547ms
Wrapped in a function = 183.4079ms
For-loop in a function = 6.3178ms

Iteration 2

Basic for-loop = 2.1239ms
Wrapped in a function = 181.3629ms
For-loop in a function = 6.408ms

Iteration 3

Basic for-loop = 1.8468ms
Wrapped in a function = 187.1938ms
For-loop in a function = 6.0039ms

Iteration 4

Basic for-loop = 2.7016ms
Wrapped in a function = 190.309ms
For-loop in a function = 6.1829ms

Iteration 5

Basic for-loop = 3.6004ms
Wrapped in a function = 191.8804ms
For-loop in a function = 6.3452ms
```

Comment: This was helpful for me, especially the excellent idea of running each test in its own scope.  I think I see some issues, though, and am going to post my own answer bc it wont fit into a comment.

Comment: @Polshgiant `Measure-Command` should run in its own scope by default imo, I'm not sure why it was designed this way. But yeah when running benchmarks if you want accurate results you need to make sure these code blocks are not looking for variables outside their scope which is what Mathias pointed in his comment

Comment: just posted my findings in a new answer, let me know if you spot any errors

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much to [@Mathias' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732918/powershell-loop-performance-why-does-adding-a-function-call-make-this-loop-fast#comment133599740_75732918) and [@Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75733931/38425).  This is an expansion of @Santiago's answer which makes a good point of running each test in its own scope, but his *basic for loop* test loses the scoping problem demonstrated by the original *basic for loop* test from the question.

Here is an updated test that:

1. restores the original 'basic for loop' test to have the scoping issue
2. adds variations to test Mathias' and Santiago's suggestions both separately and in combination
3. omits 'Variation E' (the middle variation from the original question) because it is clear why that one has such different results
4. formats timings in a table with averages

```bash
$ranGen = New-Object System.Random
$RepeatCount = 10000

$tests = @(
  @{ Variation = "A: Basic for-loop"; }
  @{ Variation = "B: Basic for-loop, local var"; }
  @{ Variation = "C: Basic for-loop, new scope"; }
  @{ Variation = "D: Basic for-loop, local var, new scope"; }
  @{ Variation = "E: Wrapped in a function (omitting)"; }
  @{ Variation = "F: For-loop in a function"; }
  @{ Variation = "G: For-loop in a function, new scope"; }
)


$runNames = 1..10 | ForEach-Object {
  $runName = "Run $_"
  $runName

  # Identical to 'basic for-loop' test from original question
  $tests[0].$runName = [Math]::Round((Measure-Command -Expression {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) { $Null = $ranGen.Next() }
  }).TotalMilliseconds)

  # Mathias' suggestion of creating and reading a locally scoped variable
  $tests[1].$runName = [Math]::Round((Measure-Command -Expression {
    $local:ranGen = $ranGen
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) { $Null = $local:ranGen.Next() }
  }).TotalMilliseconds)

  # Santiago's suggestion of adding a new scope
  $tests[2].$runName = [Math]::Round((Measure-Command -Expression {
    & {
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) { $Null = $ranGen.Next() }
    }
  }).TotalMilliseconds)

  # Both Mathias' and Santiago's suggestions
  $tests[3].$runName = [Math]::Round((Measure-Command -Expression {
    & {
      $local:ranGen = $ranGen
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) { $Null = $local:ranGen.Next() }
    }
  }).TotalMilliseconds)

  $tests[4].$runName = "--"
  # Excluding because this is by far the slowest and distracts from the original question
  # $WrappedInAFunc.$runName = (Measure-Command -Expression {
  #   function Get-RandNum_Core($ranGen) { $ranGen.Next() }
  #   for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) { $Null = Get-RandNum_Core $ranGen }
  # }).TotalMilliseconds

  # Identical to 'For loop in a function' test from original question
  $tests[5].$runName = [Math]::Round((Measure-Command -Expression {
    function Get-RandNum_All($ranGen) {
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) { $Null = $ranGen.Next() }
    }

    Get-RandNum_All $ranGen
  }).TotalMilliseconds)

  # Same as above + Santiago's suggestion of adding a new scope
  $tests[6].$runName = [Math]::Round((Measure-Command -Expression {
    & { 
      function Get-RandNum_All($ranGen) {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) { $Null = $ranGen.Next() }
      }

      Get-RandNum_All $ranGen
    }
  }).TotalMilliseconds)
}

$printProps = @(
  "Variation"
  $runNames
  @{
    Label = "Min"
    Expression = {
      ($_.PSObject.Properties.Where({ $_.Name -notmatch "Variation" }).Value | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
    }
  }
  @{
    Label = "Max"
    Expression = {
      ($_.PSObject.Properties.Where({ $_.Name -notmatch "Variation" }).Value | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
    }
  }
  @{
    Label = "Avg"
    Expression = {
      ($_.PSObject.Properties.Where({ $_.Name -notmatch "Variation" }).Value | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    }
  }
)

$tests.ForEach({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | Format-Table -Property $printProps
```

And here are the results:

```
Variation                               Run 1 Run 2 Run 3 Run 4 Run 5 Run 6 Run 7 Run 8 Run 9 Run 10 Min Max  Avg
---------                               ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ------ --- ---  ---
A: Basic for-loop                          53    31    32    35    32    35    41    32    33     31  31  53 35.5
B: Basic for-loop, local var               46    31    33    31    32    31    33    31    32     33  31  46 33.3
C: Basic for-loop, new scope               44    33    29    30    29    42    28    28    28     31  28  44 32.2
D: Basic for-loop, local var, new scope    37    24    24    24    27    32    24    24    26     25  24  37 26.7
E: Wrapped in a function (omitting)        --    --    --    --    --    --    --    --    --     --  --  --
F: For-loop in a function                  33    24    24    25    25    33    24    27    25     24  24  33 26.4
G: For-loop in a function, new scope       30    27    26    28    27    37    28    25    26     32  25  37 28.6
```

Here's what I can glean from the results:

1. Comparing variation A and F, the timings are consistent with the original question
2. The results of Mathias' suggestion of just introducing a local variable $local:ranGen (variation B) does seem to speed things up a little
3. Same with Santiago's suggestion (variation C)
4. Combining their suggestions, variation D gets performance that is equivalent on average to variation E (which is the last variation from the question).  **This seems to answer the question of why variation E is so much faster.**